# No granular scope to set the ad accounts a facebook app can see and interrogate once it has ads_read scope

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

If my application has the ads_read permission I can query by user with the access token for my app and I can see all the ad accounts a user has.

I can then also query any of the ad accounts, although some of them should not be accessible to the app that has the ads_read permission

I can see no granular scope permission that would enable me to set specific ad accounts for an app.

Is there something I am missing when I can specify what ad accounts my application can query and get insights for?

am I missing another granular scope permission that would enable this?

Regards
Mark

Comment: Have you ever fixed this?

Comment: No, nothing exists, I think it is a security issue but I raised with Facebook and they said it is working as designed and that was all. There is definitely a way in which it could be used for in proper use.